# compling error on libmicrohttpd using ld

Tags: ld

http://www.gnu.org/s/libmicrohttpd/tutorial.html#Hello-browser-example

gcc helloworld.c  -lmicrohttpd -I/opt/local/include/

helloworld.c: In function ‘answer_to_connection’:
helloworld.c:18: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
ld: library not found for -lmicrohttpd
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

I am using snow leopard with latest xcode 
and installed libmicrohttpd using macports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

never used OSX but you need something like: `-L/opt/local/lib`

Check where the lib resides.. the linked docs says `-L$PATH_TO_LIBMHD_INCLUDES`